# Magento2 : Add simple product with custom options To cart Rest API

Tags: magento2.3, php, rest-api, shopping-cart, curl

hello I need to Add simple product with custom options To cart throw Rest API I succeeded t add the simple product , price is correct and every thing is ok but unfortunately I didn't succeed  to add custom options
here is my code I'm using Curl:

```
<?php
//****************** get the token ********************//
$magentoURL = "https://--------.----------.org/";
$station = "fr";
$data = array("username" => "*******", "password" => "*********");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($magentoURL . "index.php/rest/" . $station . "/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token = json_decode($token);

$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer " . $token);
//************************* find the customer ***********************************//
$customeremail = 'email@gmail.com';

$ch = curl_init($magentoURL . '/rest/' . $station . '/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25' . 
    $customeremail . '%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$customer = json_decode($result, true);
//************************* if customer exist ***********************************//
if ($customer['total_count'] != 0) {
    $id = $customer['items'][0]['id'];
    $ch = curl_init($magentoURL . "rest/" . $station . "/V1/carts/mine");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    
    $body = '{
    "quote": {
        "items": [{
            "sku": "mysku-sku",
            "qty": 1,
            "name": "Reservation 2020",
            "price": 320,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "product_option": {
                "extension_attributes": {
                    "custom_options": [{
                            "option_id": "8227",
                            "option_value": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }],
        "customer": {
            "id": '. $id.',
            "email": "email@gmail.com",
            "firstname": "firstname",
            "lastname": "lastname"
        }
    }
';
// set body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
// send the request and save response to $response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
// stop if fails
    if (!$response) {
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }
    echo 'HTTP Status Code: ' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Response Body: ' . $response . PHP_EOL;
// close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

the response :

HTTP Status Code: 200
Response Body: []

but nothing in my cart

Answer (score 0):

Using this code I succeed add product to cart but without Custom options
type : Date and field

```
<?php

$magentoURL = "*************************";
$station = "fr";
$data = array("username" => "**********", "password" => "**********");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($magentoURL . "index.php/rest/" . $station . "/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token = json_decode($token);
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer " . $token);
//************************* find customer ***********************************//
$customeremail = '**********************';

$ch = curl_init($magentoURL . '/rest/' . $station . '/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25'
    . $customeremail . '%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$customer = json_decode($result, true);
//echo '<pre>';print_r($customer);
if ($customer['total_count'] != 0) {
    $id = $customer['items'][0]['id'];

    $customerData = [
        'customer_id' => $id
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($magentoURL . "rest/" . $station . "/V1/carts/mine");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $quote_id = json_decode($result, true);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($quote_id);
    $productData = [
        'product' => [
            'sku' => 'sku',
            'name' => 'name',
            "price" => '40'
        ]
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($magentoURL . "rest/" . $station . "/V1/products?sku=sku");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);

    $productData = [
        'cart_item' => [
            'quote_id' => $quote_id,
            'sku' => 'sku',
            'qty' => 1
        ]];

    $ch = curl_init($magentoURL . "rest/" . $station . "/V1/carts/mine/items");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }
    echo 'HTTP Status Code: ' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Response Body: ' . $result . PHP_EOL;
    
} else {
    echo 'customer doesn\'t exist';
}
```